# Security Center Disable cannot be started

Tags: windows-10, services, security-center

Security center stopped to work and I cannot change it
by Windows Services because the tabs are grayed out

[image]

I'd tried the cmd `sfc /scannow` also `winmgmt /verifyrepository`

but everything looks fine.

Can you help me with any solution?

Comment: kindly check if the methods in the following article was helpful: [4 Solutions to Windows Security Center Service Can’t Be Started](https://www.minitool.com/backup-tips/windows-security-center-service-cannot-be-started.html)

Comment: hi @Sunny I tried it before write my question and it didin't work